# Macaulay Duration?

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I have a problem with a question, I don't know if the question is well worded, it reads as follows

Having the following information about a loan:

Interest rate: 11.5% per annum, compounded monthly.

Payment frequency: monthly

Number of payments: 360

Calculate the Macaulay duration for the loan (in years).

I don't think I can do this because I don't have all the information, but I saw this [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502697/compound-interest-confirming-answer]

I hope you can help me and if something is not understood in my question I ask you an apology it is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{enclose}$
Assume the monthly payment is $X$.  Furthermore, suppose $i^{(12)} = 0.115$, so that the effective monthly rate is $j = i^{(12)}/12 = 0.00958333$, and $n = 360$ months.  Payments on the loan are made in arrears.  The Macaulay duration (in months) is
$$\frac{1}{X a_{\enclose{actuarial}{360}j}} \sum_{t=1}^{360} t X v_j^t = \frac{(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{360}j}}{a_{\enclose{actuarial}{360}j}} = n + \frac{1}{1-v_j} - \frac{n}{1 - v_j^n} \approx 93.3427,$$ where $v_j = 1/(1+j) \approx 0.990508$ is the monthly present value discount factor.  The first thing to note is that the $X$ cancels, so the Macaulay duration does not depend on the amount of payment, **assuming the payment structure is level.**